# Month Number Incrementation using measure in PowerBI

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a requirement, where I need to Increment the Month Number.

For Example,

> Jan 2016 - Dec 2016 is 1 - 12 and Jan 2017 Starts at 13. Jan 2018
>   Starts at 25.

How do we create a measure for this in PowerBI ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add calculated column:

```
MonthNumber = DATEDIFF(DATE(2015,12,1),MyTable[DateValue],MONTH)
```

Results

```
DateValue,  MonthNumber
2016-01-01, 1
2016-12-01, 12
2017-01-01, 13
2018-01-01, 25
```